# Making everything synchronized except one method

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Suppose that we have a large amount of previously-written code in which many parts may not be thread-safe. We add a method to the codes which is called somewhere at run-time which is very time-consuming but can be implemented thread-safe. Is there any way to make everything synchronized except the method, so that we can run multiple threads of the program and be sure that only the thread-safe method is run in parallel? If not, what can be done to run the method in parallel but everything else is run one-at-a-time? (Assume that due to the complexity of the code and the initializations required before the method is called we can not separate the run of the method and the rest of the code and the method is called somewhere in the middle of the run)

Comment: Can threads be running the thread-safe method at the same time some other thread is running one of the other methods? If not, then a [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) is the answer, where the "thread-safe" method takes a read lock, and all the "synchronized" methods takes a write lock (instead of synchronizing).

Comment: But I can not modify all other methods (say 1000 methods) to take a lock.

Comment: 1000 methods? And all those methods are mutually exclusive with each other? That's code smell right there. Sounds like a [God object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

Comment: Not necessarily in one class.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is that this 'thread-safe' method is called from synchronized methods, so it will run inside the synchronized block.

If this method has a return value or it alters any object which is used later inside the synchronized block then I think there is no way to solve this problem.

However if this method has no return value and any of its results are not need later in the current thread then you can implement it as an asynchronous method.

I have a similar solution in my current project: I have to log the events into an external DB. So my logEvent is an async method and although it's quite slow itself but at least it doesn't slow down the parent thread.

Comment: Indeed, its effects are used in the rest of program.

Comment: Well, maybe it's still possible to do it, but it need a LOT of refactoring and it heavily depends on the other methods. (I think my original answer is still correct, because there is no easy way to achieve it) But you have to refactor the whole code by moving the unsafe parts to smaller synchronized blocks. - But that depends on the logic. There is no theoretical YES/NO answer.